# How to completely clear screen in terminal with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to bind `Ctrl + L` to `tput reset` rather than `clear`. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nice program called [AutoKey](http://autokey.googlecode.com/), which allows you to bind keyboard shortcuts with text actions.
**To do what you need would be super easy.**
Take a look at this snapshot, you can copy paste it[image: ctrl+l in autokey]

Comment: The `keyboard.send_key("<enter>")` doesn't seem to work for terminal. The alternative `fake_keypress` does work, but with too large of a delay.

Answer (score 0):

This is not for `bash`, so I will not accept this self posted answer.

I use `zsh`, and the following at the end of my `.zshrc` file works well for me:

```
# Hard clear shortcut
function hard_clear() {
  bak_buff=$BUFFER
  BUFFER="tput reset"
  zle accept-line 
  zle -U $bak_buff
}
zle -N hard_clear
bindkey "^[k" hard_clear
```

We create a function `hard_clear()` which backs up the buffer, replaces the buffer with `tput reset`, executes, then rewrites the old buffer. This function is bound to `Alt + k`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using zsh you can just use

```
bindkey "^[k" clear-screen
```

Works just as well and no need to define a function.